# Cross Origin request - what am I missinG

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, .htaccess, cors

I have a page being served over https, say "example.com/page.php"

In that page is a jquery ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    url : "http://example.com/print/printReceipt.php",
    dataType:"jsonp",
    success:function(data)
    {
        alert("Success!");
    }
});
```

The "print" directory has an .htaccess file that includes:

```
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, PATCH, DELETE" 
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin *
```

The jquery always returns a the error:

> Mixed Content: The page at '...' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script '...?callback=jQuery300107312130929496792_1478818377085&_=1478818377088'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

What am I missing?

Comment: Read the error! Your service is https, you can't use http request from it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put also the request type into your ajax call
type:'GET'

Comment: I added "method: 'GET'" to the Ajax call, but no change.

Answer (score 0):

Seriously? You have your page, which is loaded over HTTPS, and in your script, you have this:

`url : "http://example.com/print/printReceipt.php"`

can you spot the error? (Hint: you can't mix HTTPS and HTTP).

Just use `//example.com/print/printReceipt.php`- no need to prefix with method.

Comment: See, the fact that it's calling an http page from an https page is, in fact, what makes it "Cross Origin". So yes, I could change the url to http and it would work, but that's not what I'm asking. I _want_ to call it cross-origin.

Comment: You can't. You cannot mix secure and insecure content via such calls. Hence why I told you to either use https in your call, or use a protocol neutral request with `//`

Comment: Hm. I could have sworn I read that an http call from an https page was possible through CORS. Thanks for your help.